# Make readline edit input command in external editor (similar behavior as "edit-and-execute-command" from bash)

Tags: command-line, vim, shell, key-binding, readline

## Background

So far I've found `readline` very useful since just by modifying a single configuration file (i.e. `~/.inputrc`), you are configuring all those programs that depends on `readline`.  The programs that I use in my workflow that can work along with `readline` are `maxima`, `python`, `bash`, `bc`, `lua`, `sqlite3`.

When reading the documentation on `bash`, I found the [`edit-and-execute-command` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands) and thought whether it would be possible to use that same function in the configuration file of `readline` (i.e. `~/.inputrc`) so that I could be able to use such function in every program that depends on `readline`. After trying that, I realized that  it is not listed in the [function and variable index](https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#fn_E) from the `readline` documentation, so it wouldn't be possible this way.

## The question

How can I get the behavior of **editing the input command in an external editor so that it can be executed afterwards** in any other program that use `readline` such as `python` or `bc`?

Note that by accomplishing this, I would be able to use vim with all my custom configurations

- custom keybindings.
- plugins (`vim-sandwich`, `coc.nvim`, `ultisnips`, etc.)

in each program that depends on `readline` without having to try to mimick each behavior in `readline` (by tweaking its configuration file.)

## Additional information

1. Found a [similar question](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/101452-readline-edit-execute-command) on another forum, but there is no significant answer.
2. I downloaded the (1) `bash` and (2) `readline` source code and found 16 and 1 occurrences of `edit-and-execute-command` in (1) and (2), respectively.

Comment: Note: `edit-and-execute-command` is not among [functions provided by `readline`](https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#fn_E). It seems one can [create a custom function](https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC25). It's totally out of my expertise but maybe this is what `bash` does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've already edited my question so that people won't be misled by the logical mistakes I made in writing the question.